# Mixing and matching covariates from multinom models in stargazer

Tags: r, stargazer

I'm trying to mix and match some coefficients for some multinomial logistic regression models to show how they compare in models on their own. The out put I would like is the coefficients for choice B and C for `var2` from `m1` followed by the coefficients for choice B and C for `var3` from `m2`, but for my purposes, I'd like them in two columns (e.g. B and C), not side-by-side.. Is it because the elements (Intercept) and Constant don't match up perhaps?

```
# Fake data
var1<-sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), replace = T, size=100)
var2<-sample(c(0,1), size=100, replace=T)
var3<-rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
#Turn into a data frame
df<-data.frame(var1, var2, var3)
#make multinomial models
library(nnet)
m1<-multinom(var1~var2, data=df)
m2<-multinom(var1~var3, data=df)
m3<-multinom(var1~var2+var3, data=df)

#

summary(m1)$coefficients
summary(m2)$coefficients

#This doesn't work, but I thought it would
stargazer(m3, type="text", coef=list(summary(m1)$coefficients[,2], summary(m2)$coefficients[,2]))
```

I would like to see something like this.

```
|Covariate                   | B     | C.   |
| var2 from m1               | 0.5   | -0.2 |
| std.error for var2 from m1 | (0.1) | (0.2)|
| var3 from m2               | 0.2   | -0.4.|
| std.error for var3 from m2 | (0.3) | (0.2)|
```

Comment: Would you mind to show your expected output?

Comment: I find it kinda hard to do that. I guess I can try.

Comment: I don't know the `multinom` function but is your expected output correct according to `summary(m1)$coefficients`?. Could you put in your expected output:`| var2 from m1 | summary(m2)$coefficients[1,2] | summary(m1)$coefficients[1,2] |`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The development version of my [`modelsummary` package](https://vincentarelbundock.github.io/modelsummary) includes a function called `modelsummary_wide` which can do what you want (include: self-promotion alert). This function should be available in version 0.6.3 when it appears on CRAN. Until then, you can install it from github:

```r
library(remotes)
install_github("vincentarelbundock/modelsummary")
```

Restart your R session completely to make sure the new installation takes effect. Then, simulate data and estimate two multinomial regression models using the `nnet` package:

```r
library(nnet)
library(modelsummary)

var1 <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), replace = T, size=100)
var2 <- sample(c(0,1), size=100, replace=T)
var3 <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
var4 <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
df1 <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3, var4)

var1 <- sample(c('A', 'B', 'C'), replace = T, size=100)
var2 <- sample(c(0,1), size=100, replace=T)
var3 <- rnorm(100, mean=10, sd=2)
df2 <- data.frame(var1, var2, var3)

models <- list(
  multinom(var1~var2+var4, data=df1),
  multinom(var1~var2+var3, data=df2)
)
```

Finally, we use the `modelsummary_wide` function to draw the table:

```r
modelsummary_wide(models, output="markdown")

|                    |B       |C       |
|:-------------------|:-------|:-------|
|Model 1 (Intercept) |-0.783  |0.580   |
|                    |(1.377) |(1.399) |
|Model 1 var2        |0.462   |-0.119  |
|                    |(0.479) |(0.501) |
|Model 1 var4        |0.033   |-0.091  |
|                    |(0.132) |(0.138) |
|Model 2 (Intercept) |0.635   |-0.032  |
|                    |(1.322) |(1.265) |
|Model 2 var2        |-0.457  |-0.125  |
|                    |(0.519) |(0.483) |
|Model 2 var3        |-0.045  |0.031   |
|                    |(0.127) |(0.120) |
|Model 1 AIC         |227.417 |        |
|Model 1 deviance    |215.417 |        |
|Model 1 edf         |6.000   |        |
|Model 1 nobs        |100     |        |
|Model 2 AIC         |228.988 |        |
|Model 2 deviance    |216.988 |        |
|Model 2 edf         |6.000   |        |
|Model 2 nobs        |100     |        |
```

Please note that the `modelsummary_wide` is still experimental. Its API (or even the name of the function) might change somewhat before official release.